# Theorem of Cauchy-Lipschitz reverse?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

> Theorem of Cauchy-Lipschitz.    Consider the initial value problem:
>
> $$y'(t)=f(t,y(t)), \mbox{  } y(t_0)=y_0.$$ Suppose $f$ is  uniformly
>   Lipschitz continuous in $y$ (meaning the Lipschitz constant can be
>   taken independent of $t$) and continuous in $t$. Then, for some value
>   $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a unique solution $y(t)$ to the initial
>   value problem on the interval $ [t_{0}-\epsilon ,t_{0}+\epsilon ]$

It's isn't an "if and only if" so I'm looking for a example of a Cauchy-Problem, where $f$ is not uniformly Lipschitz but there exists a unique solution same.
Could you help me if it possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

There are other conditions implying uniqueness. For instance:

- [The Osgood condition](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Osgood_criterion)
- $f(t,y)$ is continuous and decreasing as a function of $y$ for all
  $t$; then uniqueness of solutions on $[t_0,t_0+\epsilon]$ holds.

Comment: Mmm ok.. could you help me giving me an example?

Comment: $y'=-|y|^{-1/2}y$ is an example of the second type.

Comment: Isn't Lipschitz condition stronger than Osgood condition?